# Not all the charset range are being loaded when using @fontface -- How to "force" using the full charset?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

When using an arabic font with `@fontfoce` rule, something strange happens: when it comes to Roman characers, almost all the browsers (except Opera) does not use the Roman charset of the font and instead they use the charset of the other fonts declared in the `font-family` property. Let's illustrate it. Here's my `@fontface` rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'hasoobCM';
    src: url('/media/fonts/hasoob.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src:url('/media/fonts/hasoob.eot?#') format('eot'),    
          url('/media/fonts/hasoob.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/media/fonts/hasoob.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

And, here is the font declaration:

```
.hasoob { font-family: hasoobCM, Georgia, "Times New Roman"; }
```

Now, the Roman characters of the text will be that of `Georgia` and not `hasoobCM`.

And the funny part is, if I declare the font as `.hasoob { font-family: hasoobCM; }`, then the problem is sovled and the  characters render correctly. The problem is that I can not do that, because of inconsistency of the font-sizes.

So, what should I do to "force" the browsers to use all the charset of my font?

BTW, there is a `unicode-range` in the `@fontface` rule, but I don't know the exact full charset range of my font, and I'm not sure whether that will solve the issue or not.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where does this font come from, and how did you create the different font formats? Software used to generate them often defaults to including “Western European” characters only, so the question would rather be why Opera (which version? platform?) shows something else. You should provide complete code that produces the problem, or a URL of a page demonstrating that, preferably both.

Comment: @Jukka Please see [http://stackoverflow.com/q/18549923](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18549923)

Comment: the other question you have posted does not answer any of my questions.

Comment: @Jukka: It's kind of an unprofessional font that is (rather) widely used. The different formats have been created by [onlinefontconverter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/). I don't know why opera act the desired way. I can not provide any link, because it's on localhost. I think what I have written is the complete code.